# C# in Razor view output as string Literal

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

The following code from an ASPNET Core view outputs as a literal

```
<td data-sort="@weight.Date.TimeOfDay">@((ICapturedMetaData)weight).TimeCaptured()</td>
```

And by literal I mean

```
<td data-sort="23:59:59">ProjectBreathe.ClinicianPortal.Web.Models.Weight.TimeCaptured()</td>
```

I do not understand why. If I wrap the call in an Html.Enocde like this

```
<td data-sort="@weight.Date.TimeOfDay">@Html.Encode(((ICapturedMetaData)weight).TimeCaptured())</td>
```

It outputs as expected

```
<td data-sort="09:45:56.8770000">09:45</td>
```

I thought that the @ would have been enough to have it output correctly, why to I need to wrap it in an `Html.Encode` or `Html.Raw`?

Comment: The opening `@(` closes before the `TimeCaptured()` method so will output the class name.

Comment: So should I be structuring it differently?

Comment: If you open with a `@(` then the end of the expression will be the `)`, do you could wrap the whole thing in another set of parens: `<td data-sort="@weight.Date.TimeOfDay">@(((ICapturedMetaData)weight).TimeCaptured())</td>`